# Stored procedure send SSRS

Tags: sql, t-sql, smtp, ssrs-2008

I'm building an an application  where I have to send mails with an attachment of a report made in Reporting services 2008, the report has parameters, how can I build a Stored procedure where I send a report via email smtp in  format PDF or  DOC or EXCEL that expect parameters ?

I'm trying to figure out but I cant find get the answer

Comment: So is your entire app a big chunk of SQL, or is it written in something like .Net? IF you're using .Net you can call SSRS to get the report and then attach it to an email and send it.

Comment: Reporting Services allows the creation of [subscriptions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx) to deliver reports via email in a desired format. You could set default values for the parameters in the SP used in the report.

Answer (score -2):

SQL Server Reporting Services is a tool to send reports to subscribers.
This SQL Server 2016 extension will easily solve your problem (as Knightwisp suggested). Implementation details are too complex to include in this post; for those, see the below link:

[MSDN, SQL Server 2016 -- E-Mail Delivery in Reporting Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms160334.aspx)